# Query string value having "&"

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, decoding

I have a query string like

```
www.google.com?Department=Education & Finance&Department=Health
```

I have these as `li` tags and their query string is like this:

- Education & Finance
- Health

Now the problem is when I'm doing NamevalueCollection and getting all the keys value: it is giving me just Education, not Finance .....

Any idea how to resolove this?

Comment: You should URL encode before you even do that.

Comment: What are the strings coming from?

Comment: I am using it like this
NameValueCollection all = Request.QueryString;
string[] dept = all.Allkeys;
but now I can't put dept into HttpUtility.UrlEncode...its throwing error as dept is arry...it it requires string

Answer (score 8):

You need to encode your values by calling [`Server.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) before putting them into the URL.

If your values are in an array, you'll need to use a loop.  If you want precise instructions, you'll need to show us your current code.

Comment: +1 although where I work it's common practise to use Server.UrlEncode instead.

Comment: If you're writing a client app, you might not have System.Web referenced.

Answer (score 6):

The ampersand (&) is a special character in a url.  So the above URL is being interprested as www.google.com with three arguments: 2 Departments and a Finance.

Try using:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string url)
```

to encode the URL.

Comment: Hi Jeff Could you tell me how to use it with NameValueCollection..as the main problem is I am using that to get the Name and Value from the query string....

Comment: You need to use UrlEncode when you're creating the querystring.  You can encode each piece of the URL separately before concatenating them together: string URL = "www.google.com?" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Department=Education & Finance") + "&" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Department=Health");

Answer (score 3):

The values in the query string should be url encoded. Now there is no way to determine the difference between the `&` characters that separate the value pairs and the `&` character inside one of the values. Also, eventhough most browsers will accept spaces in an URL, that is invalid according to the standard.

In the value `Education & Finance` you have to encode the spaces as `+` or `%20`, and the `&` character as `%26` so that it becomes `Education%20%26%20Finance`.

So the correct URL should be:

```
www.google.com?Department=Education%20%26%20Finance&Department=Health
```